# iPhone storyboard present a model view Programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Am Developing a iphone appliction using this storyboard concept.

Here I have done the initial-view present using this storyboard.

Here I have created a button in rootviewcontroller programatically on user clicking on this button i should present another view controller lets say root2ViewController. Am using below code the present the view but its not presenting anything and it says like **identifier not found**. Any solution and idea will be appreciated.

> ```
> UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
>                                                      bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
> UIViewController *root2ViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];
> [root2ViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
> [self presentViewController:root2ViewController animated:animation completion:nil];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solution calling this below method in action is did the magic.

> ```
> [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"FindMyClinic" sender: self];
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In the inspector window in you storyboard you need to set the storyboard identifier of you view controller